# Command line tool running slowly from NSTask but fast from Terminal

Tags: macos, child-process, nstask

I have written a cmdline tool that usually takes 15-20 seconds to finish.

While it performs its task, it outputs its progress at least once per second via `stdout`.

When I run the command from Terminal.app, it performs as fast as possible, e.g. within less than 20s.

But when I run it from my GUI app, via `NSTask`, the tool takes at least 3-5 times longer.

The GUI app uses an `NSPipe` with an observer on `NSFileHandleReadCompletionNotification` to monitor the output from the tool, and that arrives frequently (e.g. at least every second).

**I tried to set the `NSTask`'s `qualityOfService` property to the higher values (up to 0x21) without any improvement.**

The task was launched from an thread (invoked via `performSelectorInBackground`) and waits for the task's completion by calling its `waitUntilExit` method.

I checked with Activity Monitor:

- **Neither the GUI app nor the tool go into App Nap mode.**
- I can see that the tool uses a constant 30% of CPU time when running from Terminal, and often drops below 10% when run from the GUI app.

I've seen the issue on 10.13.6 on two very differently configured computers. I have no yet had the opportunity to test on other OS versions, though if it doesn't work well in 10.13, that's bad enough already anyway.

**What could be causing the tool to get throttled like this?**

The tool spends most of the time in the kernel, because it invokes `searchfs()`, which scans the file system extensively. I wonder if that's part of the problem.

Also, can someone suggest alternatives for running the tool in a way that lets the GUI app keep control over its life cycle (i.e. it should be run as a child process), lets it pass arguments to the tool and read its stderr and stdout pipes?

Comment: If you really want your question deleted, don't delete its contents and ask for downvotes, mod-flag it explaining the situation and why you'd like it to be deleted. And the answer (You made a mistake) should be added as an answer, not an edit to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always increase the priority of your NSTask by launching it with:

```
nice -n *priority* *command* *arguments*
```

in which priority must be a negative number up to -20, the more negative it is the higher priority it will get.

However you will need super user privileges to launch a command like this.

You can read about it in here:

https://ss64.com/osx/nice.html

or here:

https://superuser.com/questions/42817/is-there-any-way-to-set-the-priority-of-a-process-in-mac-os-x

Comment: Thanks. But it turns out I made a mistake, passing the wrong parameters to my tool - which was causing it to take longer. So, nothing wrong with NSTask. I'd like to delete the question for this reason but I can't because it has an answer now. Oh well.